# Is $\partial_x^{-1}$ bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the differentiate operator $\partial_x: H^1(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$, it is obvious that the operator is bijective, then we can define the inverse $\partial^{-1}_x$. Is the inverse a bounded operator?

---

By open mapping theorem, it is true, however if I use Fourier transform $\hat{\partial^{-1}_xu}=\frac{\hat{u}}{\xi}$ which has a singularity at $\xi=0$, I am confused about this argument.

Answer (score 2):

The open mapping theorem doesn't apply since the map in question is not surjective. $\partial_x^{-1}$ is not even well defined on $L^2$ because you are multiplying on the Fourier transform side by ${1 \over i\xi}$ which does take some $L^2$ functions to non-$L^2$ functions.